# Syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH), expecting ')'

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-8

I want to code some associative arrays from the database in this way. But it creates some errors. I want to know what are the faults.

```
$rid = $request->input('result_id');
$passenger = Passenger::select('*')->where('result_id', $rid)->get();

$booking_data = array(
  "SearchID"  => $request->input('search_id'),
  "ResultID"  => $request->input('result_id'),
  "Passengers"  => array(
            foreach ($passenger as $key => $passengers) {
             [
               "Title"        => $passengers->title,
               "FirstName"    => $passengers->first_name,
               "LastName"     => $passengers->last_name,
               "PaxType"      => $passengers->pax_type
             ]
            }
          )
      );
```

Comment: The assigned variable is missing. And since `$key`  is not used, you can simply remove it as well. In other words, you need a variable to assign your array construct to.

Comment: You can't place a foreach inside of an array like that.

Comment: Ah... you can't put a `foreach` into an `array` definition. That's not working as is.

Comment: Is there any other way?  put a foreach into an array.  @GuidoFaecke

Comment: Set up a variable before trying to populate your booking data. `$ar = [];foreach ($passenger as $p) {$ar[] = ['Title' => $p->title,'FirstName' => $p->first_name,'LastName' => $p->last_name,'PaxType' => $p->pax_type];}` Then use  `"Passengers"  => $ar` inside of your booking data.

Comment: $rid = $request->input('result_id');
$passengers = Passenger::select('*')->where('result_id', $rid)->get();

$booking_data = [
    "SearchID"  => $request->input('search_id'),
    "ResultID"  => $request->input('result_id'),
];

foreach ($passengers as $passenger) {
    $booking_data['Passengers'] = [
        "Title"     => $passengers->title,
        "FirstName" => $passengers->first_name,
        "LastName"  => $passengers->last_name,
        "PaxType"   => $passengers->pax_type
    ];
}

Comment: thanks, @KevinY & GuidoFaecke .. its works :)